# Cannot link to chrome://newtab

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to provide a link to `chrome://newtab` (the new tab page) for my [distraction-preventing page](http://rossmasters.com/focus.html) for when I need to access it, however clicking the link gives the error `Failed to load resource`.

I've tried:

- Linking to it using `<a href="chrome://newtab">`
- Attempting to redirect the user using `window.location`.
- The `chrome:` prefix aliases to `chrome://` but still fails to load.

Does anyone know if this is possible or has any ideas to try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why it doesn't work, but I think it is for security reasons.
Pages on the internet should not have access to local resources and the new tab page is a local resource.

Comment: Mm I thought this might be the case. Oh well, I'll look into creating an extension instead.

Comment: Yes, it is by design for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Format your link thusly (also will work with firefox and other tabbed browsers):

`<a href="about://blank" target="_blank">Click me</a>`

EDIT: of course, that's not actually the new tab page.  It's just a blank tab.  Going to leave it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to write a Chrome extension to get access to the chrome://newtab link, it doesn't seem possible for an ordinary webpage to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This solution no longer works, but I'll leave it for anyone that might try to hunt down why it stopped working.

---

I finally found that `https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab` will open `chrome://newtab`, thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37287469/6038111).

Don't ask me why.

Comment: doesn't work. it goes to https://www.google.com/webhp?rct=j

Comment: @ddzzbbwwmm like I said in the edit message at the top of the answer, this method stopped working sometime in 2019.