# Chrome extension cookie in newtab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

The following code,

```
chrome.cookies.set({
    "name": "Sample1",
    "url": "chrome-extension://iiioiioacgdgbkodamplcdcffkkkfibi",
    "value": "Dummy Data"
}, function (cookie) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(cookie));
    console.log(chrome.extension.lastError);
    console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
});
```

is used to set cookies in chrome extensions. I want to customize the newtab page, and I want to store cookies, but I don't know the newtab url.
Can anyone can help me?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: What does setting cookies have to do with the new tab page?

Comment: _We don't the newtab url either._ Jokes aside, please explain your problem better.

Comment: The URL for a new tab is `chrome://newtab`. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37295301) has more additional info you may need.